# VMWare Workstation VM Will not Connect To The Internet or Host

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, windows-7

I just installed VMWare Workstation 7.1.2 on a Win7 machine a but it will not
connect to the Internet I saw it creates two VMWare Network Adaptors labeled
VMNet1 & VMNet8 with 192.168.x.x network addresses. Any reason why it will not
connect to the Internet on a default installation? It used to work flawlessly 
on XP in the past when I installed it.

Comment: Are you referring to a guest OS or the actual host itself?

Comment: Sorry I am referring to the virtual machine (I guess the correct term is guest, thx).

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Networking on the guest to **Bridged** & that worked like a charm.